# Load .env variables in .NET6 program.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Instead of using appsettings.json, I have switched to .env for my secrets because it is easier to configure with docker.

How can I inject the .env file into the builder in my .NET6 application? My current implementation is screenshotted below. But it does not work.

[image]

Comment: An `.env` file itself is not the same thing as actual environment-variables.

Comment: @Dai is there any way to load a `.env` file and add it to the builder configuration?

Comment: How about https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetEnv

Comment: What do you mean by an `.env` file in the first place? [Docker's `--env-file` argument?](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) These are used to set the container's actual environment variables. The file itself never appears inside the container. .NET doesn't care where the env variables come from, provided they have the correct names, ie they have a recognizable prefix like `DOTNET_` and a name that matches the section/name conventions

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to prefix your .env variables to avoid conflits and loading unnecessary ones.

```
MY_PREFIX__MY_SECTION__MY_VARIABLE=foo
```

```cs
var config = builder.Configuration
     // only loads variables starting with your prefix
    .AddEnvironmentVariables(s => s.Prefix = "MY_PREFIX__")
    .Build();
```

Then, you need to define a DTO that represents your environement.

```cs
// needed in order to use ConfigurationKeyNameAttribute
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;


public record MyEnv
{
    // don't specify neither your prefix nor the section here
    [ConfigurationKeyName("MY_VARIABLE")]
    public string MyVariable { get; init; }
}
```

and

```cs
var section = configuration.GetSection("MY_SECTION");

services.Configure<MyEnv>(section);
```

You can now use it in your services like so

```
public class MyService
{
     private readonly MyEnv _env;

     public MyService(IOptions<MyEnv> config)
     {
         _env = config.Value;
     }
}
```

Comment: Or the OP could use the built-in `DOTNET_` prefix

Answer (score 0):

An external library or custom code is necessary for loading .env values. There is no built-in .NET feature to handle .env files.